# What is a better way to name "The Wrong Question"?

Tags: adjectives, phrase-requests, popular-refrains, simile

On [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) I often find that people ask questions about problems that arise due to poor design choices (typically due to a lack of knowledge about the particular programming language).

For example, the OP will make a choice at point A that is wrong, then in order to correct follow-up errors goes on to B, C, D ... and at point X (s)he gets stuck, and thus asks a question about X, when the solution to the problem is actually to fix A.

Note that this is not limited to programming, but can be any project. Earlier, I came up with *The Underwater House* problem to describe a similar situation:

*Q: "I have this underwater house. I am having big problems with leaks and water damage. What is the best way to stop a leak?"*

To which the answer of course is: *"The best way is to not build a house under water."*

When faced with such a question, I often feel the urge to name it, or create some classification, to let the OP know right away what the mistake is. The best way to state this that I have come up with is: *"You are asking The Wrong Question."* However, I feel that this is inadequate, and requires further explanation.

Is there a more self-explanatory way to state this? Some simile, saying or phrase?

**Update:** I felt that no answer really fits the bill *better* than "The Wrong Question", though "treating the symptom" was arguably the best answer. The amalgam "you're treating the symptom of a design problem", while dead on the money, is not as clear, concise and pithy as one would like. And sometimes not correct.

Comment: There's a similar problem, that software folks call [yak shaving](http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2005/03/dont_shave_that.html) ;-)

Comment: Anecdotally, if you ask for directions in Ireland, you might get the response *"If I wanted to get to [intended destination] I wouldn't start from here"*

Comment: This reminded me of an anecdote that several folks on my team use as a cultural reference.  The questioner is asking you: "should I use brads?"  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rflaming/archive/2005/10/01/476154.aspx  I'd love to see this idiom take off, because it's such a common problem.

Comment: I thoroughly agree that “_The wrong question_” is better than the answers; indeed I got here by trying to formulate a request for a better expression than “_XY-question_” or “_-problem_”, which I find lamentably inexpressive. Surely in all the centuries English has existed somebody has felt the need to name this situation — or there is something we could borrow from another language.

Comment: @mcw0933: I fear your link has rotted.

Comment: Though longer, “You’re concentrating on the wrong problem” seems to me a slightly better fit, in that the questioner may be able to find a solution without asking (someone else) a question at all. But I too would like a memorable expression that feels more like a concept in its own right.

Comment: It is preferable just to _ask_ “Do you really need to build an underwater house?” – being told not to do something you do need to do is unhelpful and incredibly annoying.

Comment: Thanks @PJTraill - the Internet Archive [to the rescue](http://web.archive.org/web/20110302183615/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rflaming/archive/2005/10/01/476154.aspx)!

Comment: @mcw0933: Thank _you_! (Surprisingly bad spelling in that article.) Maybe the expression we need is something like “_a balsa (wood) nail question_” or “_are you looking for balsa (wood) nails?_”.

Comment: Something else that comes to mind for this is the concept of "mu", or "unasking the question":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#.22Unasking.22_the_question

But I still love "I told them to just use brads" as the idiom for relating one of these unenjoyable encounters.  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

X Y problem. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

From the site:

- User wants to do X.
- User doesn't know how to do X, but thinks they can fumble their way to a solution if they can just manage to do Y.
- User doesn't know how to do Y either. User asks for help with Y.
- Others try to help user with Y, but are confused because Y seems like   a strange problem to want to solve.
- After much interaction and wasted   time, it finally becomes clear that the user really wants help with X, and that Y wasn't even a suitable substitute for X.

Comment: Yep, that's it in a nutshell. However, "XyProblem" is not very self-explanatory. +1 for the funny link though. ;)

Comment: This has now become the idiomatic term to use on stackoverflow.com: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 21):

A fairly idiomatic way to express this is that "you're treating the symptom."  You need to stop treating the symptoms, and resolve the root causes, or you're just going to keep getting more symptoms popping up endlessly.

It's like taking cough medicine because your pneumonia has given you a nasty cough.  You may stop coughing, but you still have pneumonia; you've only treated a symptom.

Comment: Perhaps this combined with jwpat7's.. "You are treating the symptom of a design problem." Comes close.

Comment: This only works for me if considered as a looseish metaphor; after all a symptom suggests what the underlying problem is, while _X_ all too often fails to do so. Indeed that failure is why asking about the wrong problem can cause so much timewasting.

Comment: I would also usually prefer “_**a** symptom_” to “_**the** symptom_”.

Answer (score 16):

Say "Your question is based on a *false premise*."

From Wikipedia:

> A false premise is an incorrect proposition that forms the basis of a
>   logical syllogism. Since the premise (proposition, or assumption) is
>   not correct, the conclusion drawn may be in error. However, the
>   logical validity of an argument is a function of its internal
>   consistency, not the truth value of its premises.

In other words, if (to use your example) the premise A was false, it doesn't matter how sound the chain of reasoning was that lead from B to C to question X; the question was based on a false premise.

Comment: A poor decision is not necessarily false, though.

Comment: Yes, but you're asking for the case where the initial premise ("It's a good idea to build a house under water") leads to a question that would not have been asked if the OP realized that the premise was false.

Comment: +1. "False premise" is applicable in many more situations than "treating the symptom". Also, treating the symptom is sometimes the best (and only) thing to be done, as in the case of the common cold.

Comment: Yes, the opposite of a good decision is a bad one. However, I would prefer a solution that is not as black and white. Your premise lacks a "because...", since it is not - from every conceivable aspect - necessarily a poor idea to build an underwater house.

Comment: @TLP Think of the falseness of the premise lying in the person's belief that it's the only option, not in that it's always inherently wrong.

Comment: Actually, a valid argument from a false premise can *only* lead to a false conclusion (in strict logic), so this may be too strong.

Comment: This also neglects the fact that a questioner tackling and asking about the wrong problem is often insufficiently aware that his focus has slipped.

Answer (score 11):

A concise and sometimes-used term (see below) is "problem by design".  It will apply to a fraction of the cases you mention;  for some, making fun of the question (*e.g.*, "In that approach, the bicycle's too big for your fish") is appropriate; but for most, the phrase "not even wrong" is most suitable.

Some titles that appear in web searches for "problem by design" include "The Dioxins problem: by design or by accident?", "Remote Desktop problem, by design? - Windows XP", and "HUGE install problem by design".  The general idea behind this phrase is that problems are occurring because of the design chosen, *i.e.*, are like designed-in problems.  However, this concept will be too subtle for most bad-question-writers to grasp.

The "not even wrong" concept is not at all subtle, but perhaps applies more to answers than to questions.  For example, http://notevenwrong.blogspot.com/ writes:

> The physicist Wolfgang Pauli was once asked to comment on the work in a paper by physicist X.  Pauli's comment was that the work was so bad that it was "not even wrong."

A related but different issue has the interesting name of "[wicked problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_problem)".  Among many characterizations mentioned in the wikipedia article are "The problem is never solved definitively", "The problem is not understood until after the formulation of a solution", "Solutions to wicked problems are not right or wrong" and "Wicked problems cannot be tackled by the traditional approach in which problems are defined, analysed and solved in sequential steps. The main reason for this is that there is no clear problem definition of wicked problems."

Comment: Combined with Hellion's answer: "You are treating the symptom of a design problem." That is rather close.

Answer (score 7):

Hofstadter's *mu* could work here. *Mu* is the answer to the question "When did you stop beating your wife?" It's a way of negating or invalidating a question that cannot be answered because the presuppositions are invalid.

Comment: Do you have any further reading on this "mu"?  I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle

Comment: @TehShrike: I found [this](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/mu.html). Not much, but an interesting read nonetheless.

Comment: This sense is currently given at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mu#Etymology_2 , which you may find worth linking in your answer. I do however think that _mu_ does not suggest strongly enough that you need to take a step (or more) back and refocus your attention. “_When did you stop beating your wife?_” is not so much the _wrong question_, as just a dirty trick.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a concise way to say this. In the general case I would say "The question makes a presupposition which is invalid/wrong/inappropriate", but to challenge a particular example, I would say something like:

> Your question assumes that ...

You might find something useful under [Complex Questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_question)

Comment: Interesting. It makes me think of the [missing dollar riddle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_dollar_riddle)

Answer (score 3):

I would say "Your root issue is x, not y."

Comment: That is concise only when the problem is easily described, though.

Comment: How about "You're solving the wrong problem."

Comment: That is not a big leap from "You're treating the symptom" or "You're asking The Wrong Question", though.

Comment: @AndrewNeely: ▲, but I think “tackling” (or perhaps “attacking”, for the more aggressive of us) fits better than “solving”.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with *This is not the right question* may convey your point better than 
"You are asking The Wrong Question."